# android keyboard over EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I have a problem, the android keyboard on EditText, covers and can not be seen.

The code to reproduce the problem and be able to collaborate:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ver.javier.restjavier.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" />


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/nombre"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etNombre"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/Nombre"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:selectAllOnFocus="false" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etLugar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/Lugar"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:selectAllOnFocus="false" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etLugar1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/Lugar"
android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etLugar2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/Lugar"
android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etLugar3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/Lugar"
android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etLugar4"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/Lugar"
android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/etLugar5"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/Lugar"
android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity :**

I can not add it, there is a problem reported by the site.

**Manifiest**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:isScrollContainer="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line in the app manifest's for the activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Comment: Thank you, but don´t Work. I using Android studio 2.2.3,     compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ver.javier.restjavier"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: The problem is in the operating system version. For example, Android 4.1 does not work, 4.4 works.

Comment: It is not related with android studio version/ compile sdk version / build tools version

Comment: Android studio is the official tool, with different sdk and build tools, all from the same company that creates the operating system, hopefully it works without this problem. me pregunto como poder solucionar este pequeño problema, o si aparecerá el mismo en otra versión soportada, pero sin teléfono como para probar,